# Do tasered aliens wake up?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

In the original X-Com your little foreign buddy could wake up and run off during the mission. Does this happen in the new one, or are they out cold for the rest of the mission regardless of duration?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The aliens never wake up from their tasered state.

Keep in mind that they are still vulnerable to damage and an alien grenade, car explosion or rocket blast in their proximity will still kill the neutralized aliens, depriving you of a live captured alien.

Comment: I had one recent mission where a muton grenaded two of his stunned pals and one of my squaddies. Aliens are *bastards*.

Comment: yea i agreed they do anything to not get captured alive :)

Comment: @Shadur - this is fascinating. Do you believe he intentionally grenaded his fallen comrades to kill them? Or was the AI simply targeting your soldier who happened to be near 2 incapacitated mutons?

Comment: In retrospect, probably the latter.

Comment: Could they be mind controlled while in tasered state?

Comment: they are untargetable while in tasered state, only area effect abilities/damage like a grenade, exploding car and maybe a rift  storm (the last psychic ability) which i haven't tried on a tasered alien yet.